# Как запросить данные, не зная точно, что введет юзер

Tags: python, python-3.x, типы-данных

Задача: получить на вход два числа (x и y), каждое с новой строки.
Каждое из чисел может быть как целым, так и дробным
Какие значения введет пользователь - неизвестно.

Как реализовать?
ps Понятия не имею с чего начать, так что кода нет...

Comment: начните с декомпозиции одной большой задачи на подзадачи.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не очень представляю, как эту задачу разбить на несколько маленьких

Comment: сделайте цикл while пока не получите 2 числа, потом break. Вариант проверки Вам подсказали уже в ответах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Неизвестно, какие значения введет пользователь" - совершенно верно, всегда исходите из того, что пользователь введет не то, то вы ожидаете.

Есть задача "получить на вход два числа(x и y), каждое с новой строки", уведомьте пользователя, что от него требуется, проверьте каждое из введенных значений на возможность преобразования в число и сообщите, при необходимости, о неверном вводе.

Вместо "как запросить, не зная, что введет пользователь" должен быть вопрос "как проверить то, что ввел пользователь".

Проверить можно как-то так:

```py
x = input('введите значение числа Х:')

try:
    x = float(x)
except:
    print(f'{x} не является числом')
else:
    print(f'вы ввели {x} в качестве Х')
```

В результате:

```
введите значение числа Х:>? 3.1415
вы ввели 3.1415 в качестве Х

введите значение числа Х:>? -31415
вы ввели -31415.0 в качестве Х

введите значение числа Х:>? 3f1415
3f1415 не является числом
```

Потом сделайте по аналогии то же со второй переменной, или загоните пользователя в бесконечный цикл `while True:` с выходом после наличия двух корректных переменных.